# Efficient creation of Neo4j relationship indexes

Tags: neo4j

Can you please explain the best way to add relationship indexes to a Neo4j database created using the BatchInserter?

Our database contains about 30 million nodes and about 300 million relationships.  If we build this without any indexes then it takes about 10 hours (just calls to BatchInserter.createNode and BatchInserter.createRelationship).

However if we also try to create relationship indexes using LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider with repeated calls to index.add then the process takes 12 hours to add everything but then gets stuck on indexProvider.shutdown and doesn't complete.  The longest I have left it is 3 days.  Can you please explain what it is doing at this point?  I expected the work to be done during the calls to index.add.  What is going on during shutdown that is taking so long?

Our PC has 64GB RAM and we have allocated 40GB to the JVM.  During this shutdown step, Windows reports that 99% of the memory is in use (far more than allocated to the JVM) and the computer becomes almost unusable.

The configuration settings I am using are:

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory = 1G
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory = 1G
neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory = 1M
neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory = 1M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory = 1G
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory = 1M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory = 10G
```

We've tried changing some of these but it didn't appear to make any difference.

We have also tried adding the relationship indexes as a separate step after first building the database without any indexes.  In this case we used GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder and GraphDatabaseService.index().forRelationships.  Doing it this way seems to work although it was estimated that it would take around 6 days to complete.  We have tried invoking commit at various different intervals which makes some difference but not significant.  Most of the time seems to be spent just iterating over the relationships.

The only thing I can think of that may be abnormal about our data is that the relationships have about 20 properties on them.  But even creating an index on just 1 of these properties doesn't work.

The file sizes without any indexes are:

```
neostore.nodestore.db  400MB
neostore.propertystore.db  100GB
neostore.propertystore.db.strings  2GB
neostore.relationshipstore.db  10GB
```

Can you please give us some advice on how to get this working either during the BatchInserter process or as a separate step?

We are using version 2.0.1 of the Neo4j jars.

Thanks, Damon

Comment: I've noticed that the [batch-import](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import) project uses a custom index provider class MapDbCachingIndexProvider so I'm trying that with my BatchInserter code.  I have just started it running so will know in about 12 hours if it helps.

Comment: Do you by chance have a non Windows PC that you can run this on? I've seen immense slowdowm of batch-insert on windows. Linux and mac is 100x faster. You can also use a live-CD or just get a well equipped aws instance.

Comment: No luck with MapDbCachingIndexProvider.  It was about 5x slower creating the database.

Comment: Thanks Michael, we had planned to move to Linux anyway but might be a while before we get that (working in government and things can take a long time).  Any idea why it is so much slower on Windows?  Is it to do with the use_memory_mapped_buffers setting?  Also can you please explain what it is doing during the shutdown phase?  We can live with a 12 hour cycle at the moment but we need to resolve the problem of it just locking up at shutdown.  Thanks

Comment: During shutdown the label-scan-store is written (labels->node-ids) and the schema indexes and constraints are populated

Comment: The place where it hangs is during indexProvider.shutdown not inserter.shutdown.  The only indexes I have are the legacy style relationship indexes.  Is there anything I can do to resolve this?  Which of the various cache settings will help?  Is there something I can do to make it do more of the work during the adding of each record to the index and less in bulk at the end?  Have you ever managed to build a database of a similar size to my one with relationship indexes using the batch inserter?  Will changing from Windows to Linux stop it from locking up?